# Centering line-broken axis label in matplotlib

Tags: python, latex, matplotlib

Any idea why the ylabel isn't center justified and how I might go about centering it?

[image: ylabel not centered in plot]
Rendering text with LaTeX (`text.usetex: True`)

`ylabel('Soil Moisture Sensitivity,\n(0.01 K m$^3$ m$^{-3}$)')`

Tried adding \centering, didn't work.

Comment: This would be a good question for [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm not certain it's entirely a LaTeX issue. Matplotlib doesn't always play nice with the renderer, so I'd like to see if there's something I'm missing in my matplotlib settings before shoving more TeX in to try to solve it. I figure centering would be the default...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

did you try

`ylabel('Soil Moisture Sensitivity,\n(0.01 K m$^3$ m$^{-3}$)', multialignment='center')`?

As seen here: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/multiline.html

Comment: No, I didn't... gah! Didn't look much further than http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel, and my Google attempts failed. Thank you!